# Trying to remove accents from string in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove accents from a string and wrote the following function in php, but it's not removing them. String goes in with accents and is returned with accents.

```
function stripaccents($string)
{
    $replace = array('é','í','ó','á','ñ', 'ú', 'ü');
    $with = array('e','i','o','a', 'n', 'u', 'u');

    foreach ($replace as &$char)
    {
        $char = utf8_decode($char);
    }
    unset($char);

    $newstring = str_replace($replace, $with, $string);

    return $newstring;
}
```

Comment: I think it should work fine if you remove the foreach/unset. The utf8_decode call could mess up your replacement characters.

Comment: The key question is why you feel you need to remove the accents Use UTF-8 consistently, and you shouldn't have any problems with them

Comment: Wanda, show the input string

Comment: Input strings are spanish verbs like "reír". I need to remove accents, because I'm writing a verb test program, where accents are optional.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.3 or greater (which you should be), use the built in function:

```
$newstring = normalizer_normalize($oldstring);
```

Comment: I didn't know this function. How does it perform compared to, say [Patchwork UTF-8](https://github.com/tchwork/utf8)?

Comment: @GrasDouble It is part of the intl package. It works fine - especially for just converting short strings to ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `iconv`

```
$newstring = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
```

Comment: I tried this method and it turned my "reír" into "re'ir".

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found in PHP, you can of course customise it :

```
$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: Upper(); :: NFC;', Transliterator::FORWARD);
return $transliterator->transliterate('çÇ æ λώπηξ-É&-è_çà=@146/,*');

Output: "CC AE LOPEX-E&-E_CA=@146/,*"
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for Spanish characters in specific, you can use a regular expression to look for those specific characters:

```
function stripaccents($string)
{
    $replace = array('/é/','/í/','/ó/','/á/','/ñ/', '/ú/', '/ü/');
    $with = array('e','i','o','a', 'n', 'u', 'u');

    $newstring = preg_replace($replace, $with, $string);

    return $newstring;
}
```

Otherwise you can use one of the other functions already mentioned.

Comment: @WandaEmbar, though you might be better using a library such as [Patchwork UTF-8](https://github.com/tchwork/utf8) or [Stringy](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy).

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need

```
foreach ($replace as &$char)
    {
        $char = utf8_decode($char);
    }
    unset($char);
```

Because utf8_decode trying to convert 2 byte values from **$replace** to 1 byte value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom I am using.

```
function remove_accents($str, $charset = 'utf-8') {
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, $charset);
    $str = preg_replace('#&([A-za-z])(?:acute|cedil|caron|circ|grave|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);#', '\1', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('#&([A-za-z]{2})(?:lig);#', '\1', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('#&[^;]+;#', '', $str);
    return $str;
}
```